Get coordinates of polyline/polygon drawn by user in QGIS
QGIS 3.36.2 with Python 3.12.3
My code creates a layer (QgsVectorLayer('Point', self.layername, "memory")) that the user can draw a single polyline or polygon on. Once they are done, they press a button and my code then has to extract the coordinates of that shape (no need to export as file).
I noticed that you can draw an annotation by clicking on the layer in the map area and it automatically connects points or adds a point to the polygon. A right-click completes the shape (esc cancels) and you can even move it with "Modify Annotation". The first problem is that I've got basically no experience with QGIS, are annotations what's commonly used to manually draw on a layer and is my point layer the correct thing to use (using a memory layer because I'm going to remove the shape once I've extracted the points and there's no need to save it in the project)?
The second question: How do I extract the points?
This answer mentions the QgsAnnotationManager and, according to the docs, you can get a list of annotations and then extract their QgsFeature with associatedFeature() (and their QgsGeometry with geometry(), which hopefully contains the points) but both of these:
anns = QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().annotations()
print(len(anns)," annotations")
print(self.layer.featureCount(),"features")

... return an empty list (I drew one polygon and two polylines).
Bonus question: How do I enable that drawing mode programmatically (and disable it once a single polyline/polygon is completed by right-clicking)?

I managed to get annotations to work, instead of the QgsVectorLayer I'm now using my own QgsAnnotationLayer:
self.layer = QgsAnnotationLayer(self.layername,QgsAnnotationLayer.LayerOptions(QgsProject.instance().transformContext()))
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.layer)

Use the "Create Polygon" or "Create Line" mode (icons in the "Annotations" toolbar) to draw a polygon or polyline, afterwards you can fetch the coordinates with the following code:
items = self.layer.items() #dictionary with key and value
annotations = [*items.values()] #I don't care about the key -> extract all values

for a in annotations:
    points = a.geometry().points() #List of QgsPoint
    print(points)

This answer shows how to access and disable the annotation toolbar's buttons, depending on which mode you want your users to have access to.

You probably want to access the feature annotations stored in the "Main Annotation Layer", which is where they are stored by default.
In such case, you need to use the mainAnnotationLayer method of the QgsProject class:
QgsProject.instance().mainAnnotationLayer()

which returns a QgsAnnotationLayer object.
Then you can use the item and items methods of the QgsAnnotationLayer object to access the annotation items.

Thanks! I thought that the annotations were stored in the vector layer because they vanished when I deleted the layer but now I can't replicate that behavior for some reason. I did some testing last week and managed to get it to work with a QgsAnnotationLayer I created (still don't know what other LayerOptions there are, sadly the docs are quite lacking at points) but haven't had the time to write an answer yet. Is there an advantage of using the mainAnnotationLayer instead of creating your own that the user has access to in the "Layers" panel? Is there any alternative to annotations?

I don't think there are methods to draw georeferenced polygons other than using a vector layer or an annotation layer. The advantage of using the mainAnnotationLayer is actually to avoid to create your own annotation layer. The only LayerOptions available is the QgsCoordinateTransformContext.

Aha, thanks! My users need a way to delete the annotations, as they're saved in the project but you can't see them in the "Annotation Manager" plugin (only for text annotations). I'm currently trying to set the default color for my annotations but it's not going well (see question here). I know that you can create a symbol (with fill color,...) and use that with a vector layer, so that might be a better way (plus, you can use it as a memory layer). How do you manually draw polygons/polylines on one of those?
